# VBA error help - Error when copying sheets to new workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am getting a run-time 9 error: subscript out of range in the bolded piece of code below.Sheet5 and Sheet16 exist within mybook so I'm not sure why I am getting the error. Full code is here:

```
Sub vba_copy_sheet()

Dim mybook As Workbook
Dim filedate As String
Dim fileyear As String
Dim filemonth As String
Dim fHome As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If Month(Now()) = 1 Then
    filemonth = 12
Else
    filemonth = Format(Month(Now()) - 1, "00")
End If

If Month(Now()) = 1 Then
    fileyear = Year(Now()) - 1
Else
    fileyear = Year(Now)
End If    

filedate = fileyear & filemonth
fHome = "T:\Actuary\Metrics\Cancellation Reports\Cancelled Home Policies Summary - " & filedate & ".xlsx"

Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fHome)

**With mybook
    .Worksheets(Array("Sheet5", "Sheet16")).Copy Before:=Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    .Close SaveChanges:=False
End With**

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a workbook named Book1.xlsx open?

Comment: Yes, but it isn't saved as Book1, just opened a new workbook. Does it need to be saved to a directory first?

Comment: Are you creating this new workbook programmatically, i.e. with `Workbooks.Add`?

Comment: No I haven't created the new workbook that way. The way I expect to run this is from an newly created. already open workbook. In that case, do I need to save the new active workbook first and then I can reference in the code?

Comment: Try `"Book1"` instead of `"Book1.xlsx"`.

Comment: I still get the error when using "Book1" instead

Comment: Maybe assign Book1 or Book1.xlsx to a workbook object and use that?

Comment: Unfortunately same error when I assign Book1 as a workbook object

Comment: You can't always assume that a new workbook will be called "Book1". When you create the new workbook (`Dim newBook As Workbook; Set newBook = Workbooks.Add`), it will assign a default name (could be "Book17" for all you know). Then use the `newBook` object in your copy/paste operation.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing:

```
Before:=Workbooks("Book1.xlsx").Sheets(1)
```

to:

```
 Before:=Workbooks("Book1").Worksheets(1)
```

That works in my test.